# Recreate default colors

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color

How is it possible to specific the colors shown in the sample plot here:

[image]

The code is below and copied from the site!

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{ternaryaxis}[
    ternary limits relative,
    title={Data range $[0,1]$, limits relative},
    area style]
\addplot3 coordinates {
    (0.2,0.8,0)
    (0.31,0.4,0.29)
    (0.34,0.2,0.46)
    (0.4,0,0.6)
    (1,0,0)
};
\addplot3 coordinates {
    (0.4,0,0.6)
    (0.34,0.2,0.46)
    (0.31,0.4,0.29)
    (0.14,0.46,0.4)
    (0,0.37,0.63)
    (0,0,1)
};
\node[fill=white] 
    at (axis cs:0.56,0.28,0.16) {$F 42$};
\node[fill=white] 
    at (0.7,0.2) {$F 43$};
\end{ternaryaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. The colors from your code (after suitable completion) and those in the linked image are the same. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: do you maybe want to ask what would be the LaTeX definition of the standard plot colors or, more generally, how to define a given color (e.g. taken from a pdf) in LaTeX?

Answer (score 13):

I understand you are asking where are these `blue` and `red` colors defined when no color is mentioned into the code.

`pgfplots` uses some internally defined `cycle list`s of colors. When plots have no explicit colors, default ones are used. This way, first plot uses to be `blue`, second, red, ...

In this particular case, the plot is filled with some color, it is not only drawn. Let's try to find in `pgfplots` documentation how are this filling colors defined.

Let's start in Ternary Diagrams section (page 444 in Revision 1.10 from 2014/02/28). It says:

[image]

As you can see these colors looks like your ones. This paragraph mention that this kind of plot uses `area style` to change `cycle list`. If we click on `area style` we jump to page 95

[image]

where we click on `bar cycle list` which send us to page 82

[image]`

where we find that these filling colors are `blue!30!white` for the first `addplot3d` and `red!30!white` for the second.

Comment: +1 Ah, yes. This seems to be what the OP was asking (I didn't understood the question). I'll leave my answer in any case as it can also be helpful in other cases.

Answer (score 4):

If you are asking how to change the colors, this can be done using the `draw=<color>` and or `fill=<color>` options for the `\addplot3` commands and using your favorite colors. A little example using your code in which I added a third `\addplot3` just to illustrate how to change colors for the three regions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{ternary}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{ternaryaxis}[
    ternary limits relative,
    title={Data range $[0,1]$, limits relative},
    area style]
\addplot3 [fill=green!70!black] coordinates {
    (0.2,0.8,0)
    (0.31,0.4,0.29)
    (0.34,0.2,0.46)
    (0.4,0,0.6)
    (1,0,0)
};
\addplot3 [fill=orange!70!black] coordinates {
    (0.4,0,0.6)
    (0.34,0.2,0.46)
    (0.31,0.4,0.29)
    (0.14,0.46,0.4)
    (0,0.37,0.63)
    (0,0,1)
};
\addplot3 [fill=cyan!70!black] coordinates {
    (0,0,0)
    (0.2,0.8,0)
    (0.31,0.4,0.29)
    (0.14,0.46,0.4)
    (0,0.37,0.63)
    (0,0,0)
};
\node[fill=white] 
    at (axis cs:0.56,0.28,0.16) {$F 42$};
\node[fill=white] 
    at (0.7,0.2) {$F 43$};
\end{ternaryaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]